# How to copy a content from CICD variable to gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: unix, sed, gitlab-ci

I've an issues where in copying a content from CICD variable to gitlab-ci.yml file
CICD variable

This value I'm trying to access it in yml file where in this value replaces another value.

Here the problem that I face is while doing the replacement using sed command it doesn't copy the \n as \n instead it gives line break. But i want that \n to be pasted as it is.

```bash
PRIVATE_KEY='-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBA\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
sed -i -e \a s,PRIVATE_KEY,'-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEv\nQIBA\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n',g key.json
```

Output:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEv
QIBA
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Which isn't the one that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```bash
sed -i "s,PRIVATE_KEY,$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<< "$PRIVATE_KEY"),g" key.json
```

Here, `sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<< "$PRIVATE_KEY"` adds an escaping backslash before `&`, `/` or `\` chars in the variable text.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/HgFmLx):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
PRIVATE_KEY='-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBA\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
sed "s,PRIVATE_KEY,$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<< "$PRIVATE_KEY"),g" <<< "PRIVATE_KEY"
```

Output:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBA\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```